# Image slider with arrows and setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn how the [W3 slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) works, and have been playing around with them. I am trying to combine some of the functionalities, and ran in to an issue which I am not sure how to complete. I am using a basic slider with arrows, but I am trying to make the slider auto-slide every few seconds (and still know which slide it is at, as to use arrows for the next slide).

I have been trying to use setTimeout to change it, but gets conflicts with the change buttons. Is it not doable with this setup? Anyone who might guide me on the right path would be appreciated!

I figured it might grab it by using setTimeout to execute showDivs every 5 seconds, but that does not seem to work.

```
  setTimeout(showDivs, 5000);
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}



setTimeout(showDivs, 5000);
```

```css
.w3-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.w3-black,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important;
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.w3-tooltip,
.w3-display-container {
  position: relative;
}

.w3-display-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-left {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-right {
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-bottomleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  top: 20%;
  color: #CDA274;
}

.rotate-txt {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 2px solid #CDA274;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-top: 45%;
}

.logo-slider-fb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: block;
}

.logo-slider-ig {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.main-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%;
  left: 10%;
  color: #CDA274;
}

.main-box p {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-box h1 {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.clr-white {
  color: white;
}

.main-text {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.slider-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: #272727;
  padding: 17px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #cda274;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: 1s 2s fadeInUp both;
  animation: 1s 2s fadeInUp both;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
  background: #cda274;
}

.slider-btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.phone-logo {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.number-slide {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">

  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009427598-9c21a169f98f?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1700391373098-cd9acd1b7e7c?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700359387203-d24d08d07b04?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

  </div>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using `setTimeout()` at all the code you've shown. Please add all relevant code in to the question - ideally in an executable snippet - so that we can help you to debug it

Comment: I've updated with where I've inserted setTimeout (where I thought it would make sense) - sorry for not including!

Comment: `setTimeout(showDivs, 5000);` that's not going to work as `showDivs()` requires the `n` argument to be provided

Comment: I had that suspicion. So I will have to handle it in another function entirely?

Comment: I'm guessing that `setTimeout(() => showDivs(++slideIndex), 5000);` would work, but without seeing the complete code, this is a pure assumption

Comment: If you want more info about the `setTimeout(()=>,time)` go the link [LINK](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-bom/javascript-settimeout/)

Comment: I've linked the full code now - if I insert setTimeout(() => showDivs(++slideIndex), 5000) it "works", but if you click it a couple of times the slider goes haywire, speeding up and acting weird

Comment: Those buttons are very undynamic, having to create one for every slide i make manually - hence why I tried doing it with the one I linked :)

Comment: But yes - a combination of the two is what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like setInterval to make the call re occur, but then it would be called regardless of button pressed inbetween.
If you call setTimeout after a slide has been set, it can go to the next button after called by a timeout or after a button is pressed. However, to prevent the erratic behaviour you describe in the comments, you have to cancel the timeout call (clearTimeout) at the beginning of the call

```js
let slideIndex = 1;

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n | 1);
}

//could also use setInterval here for easier access, but then it would work regardless of when buttons are pressed
let slideTimeout = 0; 
showDivs(slideIndex);


function showDivs(n) {
  clearTimeout(slideTimeout); //in case if called from a button, to reset that timeout
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  
  //call the time out here, since showDivs is called on startup, the timeout is started too
  slideTimeout = setTimeout(plusDivs, 1000);  //1000 instead of 5000 for easier testing
}
```

```css
.w3-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.w3-black,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important;
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.w3-tooltip,
.w3-display-container {
  position: relative;
}

.w3-display-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-left {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-container:hover .w3-display-right {
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.w3-display-bottomleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  top: 20%;
  color: #CDA274;
}

.rotate-txt {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.vl {
  border-left: 2px solid #CDA274;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  margin-top: 45%;
}

.logo-slider-fb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: block;
}

.logo-slider-ig {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.main-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16%;
  left: 10%;
  color: #CDA274;
}

.main-box p {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-box h1 {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.clr-white {
  color: white;
}

.main-text {
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.slider-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  color: #272727;
  padding: 17px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #cda274;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: 1s 2s fadeInUp both;
  animation: 1s 2s fadeInUp both;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider-btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
  background: #cda274;
}

.slider-btn:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.phone-logo {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.number-slide {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">

  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009427598-9c21a169f98f?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1700391373098-cd9acd1b7e7c?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1700359387203-d24d08d07b04?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16">
        <div>
          <p class="rotate-txt">SOCIALS</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <a href=# ""><img class="logo-slider-fb" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=118497&format=png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img class="logo-slider-ig" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=48839&format=png"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-box">
        <p>TEXT TEXT</p>
        <h1><span class="clr-white">HEADLINE TEXT <br></span> HEADER</h1>
        <p class="main-text">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</p>
        <a href="#" class="slider-btn">Read more...</a>
        <a class="number-slide" href="#"><img class="phone-logo" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=256&id=12921&format=png">Call: 12345678</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>

  </div>
```

Comment: That's a great way of doing it - thanks a lot for explaining it! Great idea with cancling the timeout, I'd never thought of that!